# I am trying to remove unwanted space in my header

Tags: html, css, web

I am trying to remove this little unwanted space in the navigation bar. I have tried removing padding, margin, and border, none of which have resolved the issue. Here is my css:

```css
.nav {
  list-style: none;
  font-family: 'Oleo Script', cursive;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  float: right;
}

.header {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class=header>
  <a href="index.html">
    <img src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-IqHfCyPGn00/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAA8/WsxciIskxSo/photo.jpg?sz=328" alt="Logo.png" style="height:150px; width:150px; border-bottom: 0px;">
  </a>
</div>
```

Here is the space I am talking about:

[Unwanted Space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AX4OJ.png)

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Please provide working code or link.

Comment: this information not enough to solve your problem you need to provide more here

Comment: Do you want to remove the small space under your logo?

Comment: Please, provide the detailed code.

Comment: You have to edit(crop) your image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "img" element is an "inline" element, it's just a any other letter, like "n", "h" or .... "**p**". They have "descending" parts, and the positioning for inline elements is "baseline" (where the bottom of the "n" rests)... so what you see under the image is not a margin or padding, but the area of the line for descending part of the characters p, g ,j...
You can change the display to block, as sugessted by other answers, or simply set `vertical-align:bottom`.

The default `vertical-align` value for inline elements is `baseline`, which is the reason behind `display:block` being working... it's not **in line** content!

`line-height: 0` will also works for you if there is nothing else in the line.

Comment: I realize I should have been more thorough with my explanation. I also have a navigation bar I want to go in the header on the far right side of the screen, while the img remains on the left. I assume this changes things?

Comment: Not really, just add vertical-align to the img (to avoid this "gap") and float:right the wrapper of your navigation bar

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Your inline image has some extra margin. Give it to `display: block` and `border: 0`. It will solve your issue.

```
.header a img{
  border:0;
  display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and add this css:

```
.header a {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
.header img{
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```css
.nav {
  list-style: none;
  font-family: 'Oleo Script', cursive;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  float: right;
}

.header {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.header a {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
.header img{
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class=header>
  <a href="index.html">
    <img src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-IqHfCyPGn00/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAA8/WsxciIskxSo/photo.jpg?sz=328" alt="Logo.png" style="height:150px; width:150px; border-bottom: 0px;">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please explain this? Teach this man to fish instead of giving him fish.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following css.

```
.header a img {
display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be the default value for margin-bottom attribute. You can follow the code shared by @AnkitaPatel. But, you can also try changing the margin-bottom attribute to "margin-bottom:0px" in your CSS