# Float on images breaks overflow

Tags: html, css, css-float, overflow

```css
#overflowbox {
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 150px;
  width: 300px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

img {
  float: left; /* Removing the line fixes the issue & images are on a single line,
                  but I need to keep it to remove the vertical space between images.
                  Using 'font-size: 0' didn't work. */
}
```

```html
<div id="overflowbox">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100"><br> <!-- It should go on next line from here -->
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
</div>
<!-- The images should be on a single line -->
```

After some time, I finally found out why my code didn't work. What I tried to do was to have a line of images that were on a single line and made the container they were in overflow. But somewhy, setting a `float: left` property to the images breaks it, but I need to keep the property in order to remove the vertical space between the images.

Is there some alternative way of doing this to make it work or some kind of a fix?

Comment: you could add a secondary container around the images  - and set the width of that one to 400%

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47806994/i-am-trying-to-remove-unwanted-space-in-my-header/47814010#47814010 `display:inline-block` and `float:left` for img will work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to keep the float to remove the gaps between the images; just remove the gaps between the image tags in your code. Inline elements are sensitive to the white space on your code, so remove it.

```css
#overflowbox {
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 150px;
  width: 300px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
img {
vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<div id="overflowbox">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100"><br><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
</div>
```

Comment: @ThomasTom I updated my code example since you updated yours. Note that I changed the vertical alignment of the images in addition to what my answer states to remove any gaps between your images

Comment: It's just misunderstanding... There is no "margin" here, just whitespaces, line-heights and base line... But as there is "a gap" every body thinks margin and padding

Answer (score 0):

Check [I am trying to remove unwanted space in my header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47806994/i-am-trying-to-remove-unwanted-space-in-my-header/47814010#47814010)

`display:inline-block` and `float:left` for img will work for you.